# Bootstrap columns with vertical fluid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap with three columns for displaying news articles

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h4>Title</h4>
  <div>Article variable text</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the articles align horizontally

So instead of this:

```
 xxx xxx xxx
 xxx xxx xxx
     xxx xxx
 xxx     xxx
 xxx xxx xxx
 xxx xxx
 xxx     xxx
     xxx xxx
 xxx xxx xxx
 xxx xxx 
         xxx
```

I have this:

```
 xxx xxx xxx
 xxx xxx xxx
     xxx xxx
         xxx
         xxx

 xxx xxx xxx
 xxx xxx xxx
 xxx     xxx
 xxx 

 xxx xxx xxx
 xxx xxx
```

How can I resolve the alignment in a simple way?

Comment: It's very easy with bootstrap, you just need to think columns before rows instead of rows before columns... see example below

Answer (score 0):

You have to make 3 `col-md-4` and inside of them another row and then you can use your articles with `col-md-12`

In [Emmet](http://emmet.io/) this would look like this

```
.container>.row>.col-md-4(>.row>.col-md-12*10)*3
```

Comment: The result I'm looking for is not having rows, so that the articles will be fluid vertically

Comment: Well there is no other way, unless you want to use Javascript to read out the heights of these Columns and then calculationg wich one would be the best to put together.

Answer (score 0):

One option is a CSS3 approach like this using 'column-width'..

http://www.bootply.com/120682

Another option is a plugin like Isotope or Masonry. Here is an example using the Isotope plugin...

http://www.bootply.com/108697

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- this is the left column. -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <article>
            <h4>Title</h4>
            <p>Text</p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h4>Title</h4>
            <p>Text</p>
        </article>
    </div>

    <!-- this is the center column. -->
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <article>
            <h4>Title</h4>
            <p>Text</p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h4>Title</h4>
            <p>Text</p>
        </article>
    </div>

    <!-- this is the right column. -->
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <article>
            <h4>Title</h4>
            <p>Text</p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h4>Title</h4>
            <p>Text</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```